# doto and setting property conditionally

Tags: clojure

I want to write:

```
(defn download-web-page
    "Downloads the webpage at the given url and returns its contents."
    [^String url ^String user ^String password]
    (with-open [client (doto (WebClient.)
                       (when user (.set_Credentials (NetworkCredential. user password ""))))]
    (.DownloadString client url)))
```

So I want to set the credentials only when they are given as an argument to the function. However it doesn't seem to work that way - and neither does it when I replace the when with an if.

The function works fine if I remove the when altogether.

I guess I can't use a when in a doto - are there nice ways to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just write it as:

```
(defn download-web-page
  "Downloads the webpage at the given url and returns its contents."
  [^String url ^String user ^String password]
  (with-open [client (WebClient.)]
    (when user
      (.set_Credentials client (NetworkCredential. user password "")))
    (.DownloadString client url)))
```

`with-open` doesn't impose any particular demands on `client`, except that it have a no-arguments `close` method, so you do not need to "finish" it in any sense within the bindings vector.

Comment: I assumed from the way it was written that the credentials needed to be set before the connect is opened.  Your code opens first, then sets credentials.  I don't know if that's a problem or not.

Comment: No, with-open does not open anything.  It *only* guarantees that the bound variables are (.close)d when control flow leaves the with-open form, whether by exception or normal return.

Answer (score 4):

(Note: This should all hopefully work, but I cannot test it at this time. Please give it your own sanity check.)

You could write

```
(defn download-web-page
  "Downloads the webpage at the given url and returns its contents."
  ([^String url] (download-web-page url nil nil))
  ([^String url ^String user ^String password]
     (with-open [client (doto (WebClient.)
                          (-> (.set_Credentials
                               (NetworkCredential. user password ""))
                              (->> (when user))))]
       (.DownloadString client url))))
```

That seems pretty convoluted to me, though. Another approach:

```
(defn download-web-page
  "Downloads the webpage at the given url and returns its contents."
  ([^String url] (download-web-page url nil nil))
  ([^String url ^String user ^String password]
    (with-open [client (let [c (WebClient.)]
                         (when user
                           (.set_Credentials
                            (NetworkCredential. user password "")))
                         c)]
      (.DownloadString client url))))
```

The convoluted `->` / `->>` pattern from the first version could be abstracted away with a macro:

```
(defmacro doto-guard [guard action]
  `(-> ~action ~guard))
```

Then you could write

```
(doto (WebClient.)
  (doto-guard (when user) (.setCredentials ...)))
```

This has the nice property that you could use it multiple times in a single `doto` form while mixing in regular `doto` clauses. Well, it's nice if this sort of thing comes up more often in your code, anyway. Otherwise the `let`-based version should do fine.

(If that pattern comes up *really* often for you, the macro could be made more flexible... It's also tempting to make it slightly *less* flexible, but prettier, say by replacing `~guard` with `(when ~guard)`, so that at point of use one would write `(doto-guard user (.setCredentials ...))`. Any deep reason to choose a particular version would have to come from a broader context, however.)

The split into two function bodies is just a matter of style -- I prefer not to write the `nil nil` when no credentials are actually provided.

Comment: This answers Kurt's literal question, but he is asking the wrong question.  Simpler code can accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Although I resent the "wrong question" bit somewhat, dreish is right. +1 for suggesting the overload without user and password.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend either of you.  I ask wrong questions all the time.  I'm pretty sure everyone does.

Comment: @dreish: No offense taken. I found it interesting to approach the general problem of performing parts of `doto` forms conditionally (while hopefully avoiding weird, unnatural macros), but upon a second look your answer definitely seems to provide the cleanest solution to the actual problem at hand. +1 for that. @Kurt: Sure. Happy to be of some help.

Answer (score 3):

You can nest `cond->` inside of `doto` like so:

```
(doto (java.util.Vector.)
  (cond-> (= 1 1) (.add "bla")))
;; => ["bla"]

(doto (java.util.Vector.)
  (cond-> (= 1 2) (.add "bla")))
;; => []
```

Which gives you a conditional doto.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn download-web-page
  "Downloads the webpage at the given url and returns its contents."
  [^String url ^String user ^String password]
  (let [client (WebClient.)]
    (when user 
      (.set_Credentials client (NetworkCredential. user password "")))
    (with-open [client client]
      (.DownloadString client url)))
```

The `(with-open [client client]...` looks a bit weird, but hey, it's a nasty bit of stateful code.  If that conditional setting in `doto` comes up frequently enough, it *may* warrant a macro, but I would jump to a builder function first:

```
(defn build-web-client
  [^String user ^String password]
  (let [client (WebClient.)]
    (when user 
      (.set_Credentials client (NetworkCredential. user password "")))
    client))

(defn download-web-page
  "Downloads the webpage at the given url and returns its contents."
  [^String url ^String user ^String password]
    (with-open [client (build-web-client user password)]
      (.DownloadString client url)))
```